# running function in lambdas

Tags: python, lambda

I have define some function. I tried to use lambdas insted of using for loop. But can't able to figure out why it is not working.

my function is like:

```
def dis_find(df,X,Y):
    base = (df.x[X],df.y[X])
    inter = (df.x[Y],df.y[Y])
    dis = (vincenty(base, inter).km)
    return np.round(dis)
```

where df is my data-frame, and X and Y are Coordinates. Value of X is constant but Y will be from the list.

instead of using for loop i tried:

```
list(map(lambda Y : dis_find(df,tr_stn,Y),Y))
```

Here Y is the list of Coordinates.

Error massage is df is not define? How to do that?

Comment: Show how you are using the code with the lambda to replace a for loop. We can't see if `df` is defined or not from what you've posted here.

Comment: So, is `df` actually defined? That is, is there a variable that's named `df` in your code?

Comment: So can't we use map(lambda Y : dis_find(df,tr_stn,Y),Y) to get values? ..Sorry  I am very new :(

Comment: yes it works with for loop like just like: for i in np.arange(lenY): dis = dis_find(df,tr_stn,Y[i])